# create dynamic line with circles in each end and parameters for width height and rotation for the line - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need help to create a function to create x quant of lines with circles in each end of the line using parameters to define the angle of rotation, width,height and color of the line and fill the space between the lines, the propours of this is making a kind of rotation max and min angle of the human arm and shoulder.

this is a image of ilustrative example what i need to do, the image of the person model is fine in png i need just to create dynamic lines.

[image]

this is the code i have so far:

```js
function drawLine(deg,width,height,canvasId,color){
  const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.rotate(deg);
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
drawLine(0,200,3,'canvas','red')
drawLine(120,200,3,'canvas1','blue')
```

```css
canvas{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the picture I will assume 180deg is the reference point of 0. Anything out from there is where we start counting degrees. If that is the case you will want to run a function that calculates the angle between a solid line at 180deg and two other lines from that point.

In total you will need four points. You starting point for all references (pointB in this example), another point (pointD) will be used to set the angle reference to 0 degrees. We will measure the next two angles from this line.

PointA and PointC can be adjusted as needed and we then calculate the angle from pointD/pointB vector. We can use `Math.atan2` to calculate the angles of BA and BC move away from BD.

```
let angle1 = Math.atan2(distBC_x * distBD_y - distBC_y * distBD_x, distBC_x * distBD_x + distBC_y * distBD_y);
```

In this snippet I changed the color of the lines to make it easier to see what is what. You also won't need to draw the pink line. This is static so you will need to create limits and a dynamic method to change the angles.

Change the x value of pointA and pointC to change the Min and Max. Keep in mind I have to restrictions set for you to be able to switch them.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
//change pointA and pointC x value. 
//pointA sould be your Min
//PointC should be your Max
let pointA = {x: 200, y: 250};
let pointB = {x: 250, y: 100}; //common point
let pointC = {x: 120, y: 250};
//only used to set reference to 0 at 180 degrees
let pointD = {x: pointB.x, y: pointB.y + 150};

//creating our vectors length
let distBA_x = pointB.x - pointA.x;
let distBA_y = pointB.y - pointA.y;

let distBC_x = pointB.x - pointC.x;
let distBC_y = pointB.y - pointC.y;

let distBD_x = pointB.x - pointD.x;
let distBD_y = pointB.y - pointD.y;

//calculate angle between pink and purple
let angle1 = Math.atan2(distBC_x * distBD_y - distBC_y * distBD_x, distBC_x * distBD_x + distBC_y * distBD_y);
if(angle1 < 0) {angle1 = angle1 * -1;}
let degree_angle1 = angle1 * (180 / Math.PI);

//calculate angle between purple and red
let angle2 = Math.atan2(distBA_x * distBD_y - distBA_y * distBD_x, distBA_x * distBD_x + distBA_y * distBD_y);
if(angle2 < 0) {angle2 = angle2 * -1;}
let degree_angle2 = angle2 * (180 / Math.PI);

function draw() {
  ctx.textStyle = 'black';
  ctx.font = '20px Arial';
  ctx.fillText('Max = '+ degree_angle1, 100, 20);
  ctx.fillText('Min = '+ degree_angle2, 100, 50);
  
  //Lines
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'purple';
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pointA.x, pointA.y); 
  ctx.lineTo(pointB.x, pointB.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pointB.x, pointB.y); 
  ctx.lineTo(pointC.x, pointC.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'pink';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pointB.x, pointB.y); 
  ctx.lineTo(pointD.x, pointD.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  //Points
  ctx.fillStyle = 'purple';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(pointB.x, pointB.y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(pointA.x, pointA.y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(pointC.x, pointC.y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  //Fill
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(113, 0, 158, 0.3)'
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pointA.x, pointA.y);
  ctx.lineTo(pointB.x, pointB.y);
  ctx.lineTo(pointC.x, pointC.y);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  
}
draw()
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Not a problem at all